# Erro ao instalar apk pelo adb adb: failed to install meu.apk:

Tags: android

Como todos sabem, a partir de agosto de 2019, [será necessário enviar o apk pronto para a arquitetura 64](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/01/get-your-apps-ready-for-64-bit.html). Já estou testando o app para verificar se ele funciona normalmente na arquitetura 64, estou seguindo esse [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/64-bit) para isso. Mas quando rodo o comando `adb install --abi arm64-v8a meu.apk` não instala o app e retorna um erro vazio `adb: failed to install yoooup.apk:`. Se uso o comando `adb install --abi armeabi-v7a meu.apk` instala e funciona normalmente.

Tentei reiniciar meu aparelho android, reiniciar o adb (`adb kill-server` e `adb start-server`) e até gerei outro apk.

Answer (score -2):

Verifique se eu aparelho tem a arquitetura x64, estava com o mesmo problema com um Moto G4 play usando `adb install --abi arm64-v8a meu.apk` e funcionando com o comando `adb install --abi armeabi-v7a meu.apk`, após trocar para um outro aparelho (um S10 +) ele funcionou com ambos os comandos.

Answer (score -3):

Tente instalar usando o próprio adb através da linha de comando, porém outra

**Exemplo:** adb -s yourdeviceID install -r build/app/outputs/apk/app.apk

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).